# MIDORY_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED: No minimize, close& restore buttons

Tags: browser, xfce, default-settings

I've installed midori browser in Arch Linux (w. xfce4) and it starts automatically with maximized window size (not full screen but maximized). The problem is that the maximized browser window does not have the "minimize, restore & close" buttons that all the windows have at the top-right corner:

[image: window buttons]

These buttons don't show up in the maximized midori browser window (they do show up if I start midori with a non-maximized window).

I've checked the browsing preferences, but I could not find how to enable this under the view menu nor under the browsing preferences. I also tried removing this line in ~/.config/midori/config :

```
last-window-state=MIDORI_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED
```

and then the browser starts with a different window size and with the buttons at the top-right corner. But as soon as I maximize the browser window, the buttons are gone.

How could I customize the settings to get these buttons when the midori browser is maximized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1492932):

> When using Midori with gtk3 enabled, Xfwm (Xfce 4.12) shows no window
> decorations around the Midori window. The gtk3 client side decorations
> are also missing, making it impossible to close and minimize the
> window without the task bar.
>
> This only happens when the window is maximized. When the window is not
> maximized, the window decorations are shown, as expected.

There is a patch attached which is already commited. The problem should disappear once Midori 0.5.12 is released.

I'm using Gentoo and successfully applied the patch on my system. I can confirm that it fixes the problem.